# Milestones on the path of spiritual progress

Tags: spirituality

Can anyone please enumerate point by point what are the milestones on the path of spiritual life? How we measure the progress, if any? Quoting from the shastras and/or Teachings from the Sages and saints would be a great help. Thanks!